# Extend WooCommerce cart item block with custom html and data

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-blocks

Since WooCommerce 8.3 Cart and Checkout Blocks are the new default.

I'm maintaining a plugin that adds some custom html to each cart item by using the woocommerce_after_cart_item_name hook. This works fine for the classic cart, but doesn't seem to work anymore on cart blocks.

The HTML we add looks something like the following en is enriched with data (id) from the database which is stored on the cart item by using add_meta_data.

```
<div data-id="idFromDatabase">Text</div>
```

I'm looking for a similar solution for WooCommerce cart item blocks. Preferably by using php.

I tried using the window.wc.blocksCheckout library and registerCheckoutFilters functionality. This way the HTML can be altered but I don't have access to the ID stored in the database. We also run a custom javascript that does something with this html which should run after the cart item is altered.

Comment: Note that JavaScript/jQuery doesn't work with Blocks (as ReactJS is used).